# Unable to import 'scrapy_splash' pylint(import-error)

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pylint, scrapy-splash

when trying to import Splash Request in VS Code, I get the following error message:

```
Unable to import 'scrapy_splash' pylint(import-error)
```

Do you know why this is the case? I have Splash up and running and the package is installed in my environment. I am using Python 3.7

[Here is a screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krAdi.png)

Comment: Do you really have that package (`scrapy-splash`) installed? What's the result of `pip freeze | grep -i scrapy`?

Comment: Hi Tomas. Thank you for your answer. Yes I believe so: Scrapy==1.5.2
scrapy-splash==0.7.2

Comment: And does VS Code use the correct virtual environment? I don't know VS Code, so I can only link to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) here.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!  You were right, I was in the wrong environment. For anyone who reads this later. You can change the environment in the command pallete (Ctrl+Shift+P) and enter Python: Select Interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I was in the wrong environment. You can change the environment in the command pallete (Ctrl+Shift+P) and enter Python: Select Interpreter